# SearchBar & Display in table view with Coredata using Swift?

Tags: swift, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, uisearchbardelegate

I am new to iOS development and am in my second app with Swift. I am unable to incorporate SearchBar & Display search in my Table view controller.

There are 2 views in my app. First View generates an Array of fruits. Output of First View: [Apple, Orange, Banana, Pears]. Then [Pomegranate, Pears, Watermelon, Muskmelon] and so on. One array at a time.

Each array of fruits is stored in core-data using NSFetchedResultsController to be displayed in a tableviewcontroller. 
My Coredata layout:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

@objc(Fruits)

class Fruits: NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged var date: String
    @NSManaged var fruit: String
}
```

My Second View displays the list of fruits. Now I have added a Search Bar & Display on top on the table view. But I am unable to make it work.

Protocols used:

```
class HistoryTableViewController: UITableViewController, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate{
```

Variables declared:

```
let managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext? = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as? AppDelegate)?.managedObjectContext
var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController?
var fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Fruits")
```

There are two outlets in my class:

```
@IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar! // the Search Bar & Display
@IBOutlet var tblHistory: UITableView! = nil // Table View
```

Data population for table view:

```
override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return fetchedResultsController?.sections?.count ?? 0
    }
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {   
        return fetchedResultsController?.sections?[section].numberOfObjects ?? 0
    }

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: (NSIndexPath!)) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
            if let cellFruit = fetchedResultsController?.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as? Fruits
            {
                cell.textLabel?.text = cellFruit.fruit
                cell.detailTextLabel?.text = cellFruit.date
            }
            return cell
    }

    // Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
        // Return false if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
        return true
    }

    //MARK: NSFetchedResultsController Delegate Functions
func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController, didChangeSection sectionInfo: NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo, atIndex sectionIndex: Int, forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType) {

        switch type {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeType.Insert:
            tableView.insertSections(NSIndexSet(index: sectionIndex), withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade)
            break
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeType.Delete:
            tableView.deleteSections(NSIndexSet(index: sectionIndex), withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade)
            break
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeType.Move:
            break
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeType.Update:
            break
        default:
            break
        }
    }

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
            //Delete object from entity, remove from list
            if editingStyle == .Delete {
            }
            switch editingStyle {
            case .Delete:
managedObjectContext?.deleteObject(fetchedResultsController?.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! Fruits)
                do {
                    try managedObjectContext?.save()
                }catch{}
                print("Fruit set deleted successfully.")
            case .Insert:
                break
            case .None:
                break
            }
        }
func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController, didChangeObject anObject: AnyObject, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?, forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: NSIndexPath?) {

        switch type {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeType.Insert:
            tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths(NSArray(object: newIndexPath!) as! [NSIndexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade)
            break
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeType.Delete:
            tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths(NSArray(object: indexPath!) as! [NSIndexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade)
            break
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeType.Move:
            tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths(NSArray(object: indexPath!) as! [NSIndexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade)
            tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths(NSArray(object: newIndexPath!) as! [NSIndexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade)
            break
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeType.Update:
            tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath!)
            break
        default:
            break
        }
    }

    func controllerWillChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {
        tableView.beginUpdates()
    }

    func controllerDidChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {
        tableView.endUpdates()
    }
```

How do I Search any fruit from coredata and filter on the view?
Which delegate function should be used for the search bar & display functionality in Swift coding?

Any help on a concept I might have missed somewhere in here would be appreciated! Thanks.

**Update:** as Daniel Eggert suggested I am trying to use predicate for the Search Controller functionality, but the Predicate always gives a **nil**. What am I missing???

Variables declared in class:

```
var results: NSArray = []
var searchPredicate: NSPredicate?
var searchController: UISearchController!
```

Predicate Functions:

```
//Search Functionality
        func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController)
        {
            let searchText = self.searchController?.searchBar.text
            if let searchText = searchText {
                searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "fruit contains[cd] %@", searchText)
                results = (self.fetchedResultsController!.fetchedObjects?.filter() {
                    return self.searchPredicate!.evaluateWithObject($0)
                    } as! [Fruits]?)!
            self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }

    // Called when text changes (including clear)
    func searchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String)
    {
        if !searchText.isEmpty
        {
            var predicate: NSPredicate = NSPredicate()
            predicate = NSPredicate(format: "fruit contains [cd] %@", searchText)
            let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "date", ascending: true)
            fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
            fetchedResultsController?.fetchRequest.predicate? = predicate
            print(fetchedResultsController?.fetchRequest.predicate) // this is always nil. Why????????????
            do {
                try fetchedResultsController?.performFetch()
            }catch{}
            print("results array: \(results)") // this array should have values of the table view, but is empty. Why ?????????????????
            fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: managedObjectContext!,
                sectionNameKeyPath: "fruit", cacheName: nil)
            fetchedResultsController?.delegate = self
            tableView.reloadData() 
        }
    }
```

Comment: If the search bar text length is 0, how to handle it?

Answer (score 0):

You want to set a predicate on you fetched results controller.

Once you've changed the fetch request on the fetched results controller you need to call `performFetch()` to have it refetch its data. Then call `reloadData()` on the table view.

Text search for non-trivial examples can be tricky to do right, though, due to how languages, locales, and Unicode interact. I'd recommend the *Text* chapter of my book: https://www.objc.io/books/core-data/

Comment: Daniel please suggest whether the approach I have taken is right. the _Text_ chapter in your book is accessible upon purchasing it.

Comment: beautiful book, purchased and I love it.  Finally some in depth Swift/iOS examples & practical approaches. 10/10 would recommend

Answer (score 0):

If you want to implement searchable tableView? You're must must use `UISearchResultsUpdating` protocol method instead of the `UISearchBarDelegate` protocol method called `searchBar:textDidChange`. You can use `searchBar:textDidChange` method when `UISearchResultsUpdating` protocol method is not available! Both classes are useful and powerful. And easy to implement